# Logging the request details before message builder in Axis2

Tags: web-services, logging, request, apache-axis

Is there a way to log the request before building the message in Axis2. Overhead of enabling wire logs is high and I only need to log request time, http headers, http method, request URI, etc... Here I cannot use Axis2 handler since it engage after building the message. So my question is how to log the request details before message builder in Axis2.